# Show form in Custom Installer in C#.Net

Tags: c#

```
 [RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class Installer1 : Installer
{
    public Installer1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public override void Install(System.Collections.IDictionary stateSaver)
    {
        base.Install(stateSaver);
    }
    private void Installer1_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 topmostForm = new Form1();
        topmostForm.BringToFront();
        topmostForm.TopMost = true;            
        topmostForm.ShowDialog();
     }
 }
```

When i Call topmostForm.ShowDialog() that time form is shown in back side of default installer screen.
I want to it front side.
I think you got my idea.... 
Please help me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me was to call `Activate` from the `Form.Load` event.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Active();
}
```